# How can i resolve an error occurring when sending a patch from the Zoom API using Google Apps Script

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, zoom-sdk

I attempted to send a patch of the Zoom API update user setting using GAS(Google-apps-script).
However, the following error occurs.

it has been confirmed that the API operates without problems in Postman.
there appears to be no problem with the OAuth token itself.

Given the following code :

```
function test_updateUserSetting(){

  let userEmail = "Zoom User Email"
  let url = 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/' + userEmail + '/settings'

  const token = getToken() // get OAuth token
  Logger.log(token)


  let raw = JSON.stringify({
    "feature": {
      "webinar": true,
      "webinar_capacity": 500
    }
  });

  let requestOptions = {
    'method' :  'PATCH',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
    'payload': raw
  };

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  let user = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  console.log(user)
}
```

Error message that occurred :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

what part of the code needs to be modified to make it work properly?

I'm trying the Update User Setting API of ther Zoom API.
The relevant reference URL for that API is as follows :
https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/userSettingsUpdate

Comment: I think that the reason for your current issue of `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` is `'contentType': 'application/json'`. In this case, please add `,` after `'contentType': 'application/json'` like `'contentType': 'application/json',` and test it again. So, modified `requestOptions` is `let requestOptions = { 'method': 'PATCH', 'contentType': 'application/json', 'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }, 'payload': raw };`.

Comment: @Tanaike
I'm sorry.
It was my mistake to leave out the comma.
I think I made a typing mistake while pasting the code.
Thank you for your answer.
As you said, i ran the code containing the comma, but the same error occurred.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `As you said, i ran the code containing the comma, but the same error occurred.`, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike
It's okay.
Thank you for you replying.
I apologize for causing confusion due to an error in the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. By the way, your current error message is `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` with your updated script. If my understanding is correct, when you run the script, such an error occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike
yes, your understanding is right. 
`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` is my current error message with my updated script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, when you run your showing script, does an error of `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` occur? Or, when you save the script, does the error occur?

Comment: @Tanaike
the error of `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` is occured when i run my current script, not when i save the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `the error of SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input is occured when i run my current script, not when i save the script.`, in your situation, I understood that the script can be saved. When you run the script, where line does the error occur?

Comment: @Tanaike
the line where the error occurs is here :`let user = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in that case, when you put `console.log(response.getContentText())` just after the line of `let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);`, what value will you see in the log? From your provided official document, I'm worried that no value might be returned. https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/userSettingsUpdate If the returned value is `""`, I'm worried that such an error occurs. If my understanding is correct, I think that your request worked fine.

Comment: What is output of code Logger.log(response);?

Comment: @Tanaike
thank you for replying.
As you instructed, i ran the code `console.log(response.getContentText())` is located after `let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);`.
The result was "", and it was confirmed that the result of User Setting was updated. thank you for your support!!

Comment: @Jai
the output of code `Logger.log(response);` was below :
{ toString: [Function],
getResponseCode: [Function],
getContent: [Function],
getHeaders: [Function],
getContentText: [Function],
getAllHeaders: [Function],
getBlob: [Function],
getAs: [Function],
}

However, i solved this issue!
thank you for your replying.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, it was found that the returned value is empty. That was the reason for your current issue. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike
it was my first time to use stack overflow, so i didn't know i should upload the answer by myself.
i uploaded the answer and thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by modifying the code as follows.
The cause of the error was that the return value of the API transmission returned as blank. 
To solve this problem, the code was modified to treat the API transmission as successful if the response code was 204.

```
function test_updateUserSetting(){

  let userEmail = "Zoom User Email"
  let url = 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/' + userEmail + '/settings'

  const token = getToken() // get OAuth token
  Logger.log(token)


  let raw = JSON.stringify({
    "feature": {
      "webinar": true,
      "webinar_capacity": 500
    }
  });

  let requestOptions = {
    'method' :  'PATCH',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token},
    'payload': raw
  };

  try{
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
    if(response.getResponseCode() === 204){
      console.log("update successed")
      return true
    }else{
      console.log("update failed")
      return false
    }
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e)
    return false
  }
}
```